# Langchain predict function call parsing error

Tags: debugging, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, palm

```
if topic:
    llm = GooglePalm(google_api_key=google_api_key)
    llm.temperature = 0.1
    template = "Tell me reasons why I am having these symptoms {topic}.
    prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(template)
    chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt = prompt)
    try:
        chain.predict(topic=topic)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during chain running: {e}")
        return "An error occurred while processing the chain."
```

I am getting Error during chain running: list index out of range when it runs chain.predict(topic=topic)?
It is coming from this output parser that langchain is using:

/langchain/schema/output_parser.py", line 226, in parse_result
return self.parse(result[0].text)
~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

Why is this the case?

It should just output some text but it is unable to parse it using the predict function.

Answer (score 0):

Google Palm is blocking your query due to safety reason.

Google Palm's response:

```
{
  "filters": [
    {
      "reason": "SAFETY"
    }
  ],
  "safetyFeedback": [
    {
      "rating": {
        "category": "HARM_CATEGORY_MEDICAL",
        "probability": "HIGH"
      },
      "setting": {
        "category": "HARM_CATEGORY_MEDICAL",
        "threshold": "BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have raised the [issue](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/13532) on langchain for relaying the correct error message of Google Palm.

Meanwhile you can test your basic prompts through curl like this to see what Google Palm is sending as response:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "prompt": { "text": "Tell me reasons why I am having symptoms of cold"} }' "https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta3/models/text-bison-001:generateText?key={PASTE_YOUR_KEY_HERE}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to recreate your vector db reducing the chunk size and overlap. That worked for me.

<Kindly ignore the above answer given - It is not correct answer to this problem>

As pointed out by other contributors - take a look at the safety settings in the Palm API